# How to test a Validator which implements ConstraintValidator in java?

Tags: java, validation, testng, bean-validation, custom-validators

I have an "AllowedValuesValidator.java" class:

```
public class AllowedValuesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AllowedValues, String> {

    String[] values;
    String defaultValue;

    @Override
    public void initialize(AllowedValues constraintAnnotation) {
        values = constraintAnnotation.allowedValues();
        defaultValue = constraintAnnotation.defaultValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(defaultValue) && StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            value = defaultValue;
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value) && !Arrays.asList(values).contains(value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding interface class:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AllowedValuesValidator.class)
public @interface AllowedValues {

    String message();

    String fieldName();

    int fieldNumber();

    String[] allowedValues() default {"Y", "N"};

    String defaultValue() default "";
}
```

I want to be able to write a unit test class to test the direct logic in that validator. But it seems that most places I googled give examples of test classes where we basically test all validators for a given Model class, for example:

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmailExistsIncorrect() {

        Set<constraintviolation<usercredentialsdto>> violations = validator
                .validate(credentials, UserCredentialsDto.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }
```

I don't want to build mock models to test all validators.
Is there a way to create a separate test class for just testing the logic in one single validator directly without using any other model classes etc?

Comment: Actually I I created myself a small mock class within the testing class and validating the properties in that class seems to be easy enough so this will work for me fine.

Comment: According to the official docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html), the isValid() method requires to be threadSafe. When setting this class's attributes using initialize; is it thread safe? Is a new instance of this validator class created for every single field that is being validated?

Answer (score 14):

You can test the validator standalone. The rub is of course the initialize method, since it needs an instance of the annotation. You basically have three options:

1. Add a second initialize method which takes the required parameters directly. You can then use this method to initialize the validator. You can also make this method just package visible, provided your test resides in the same package
2. Place the test annotation somewhere into your test class and retrieve it via reflection in order to pass it to the initialize method.
3. Use annotation proxies. This is also what Hibernate Validator itself uses internally for in case constraints are configured via XML or needed for tests. There are two classes in Hibernate Validator which you could use `AnnotationDescriptor` and `AnnotationFactory`. The code would somewhat like this:

--

```
private AllowedValues createAnnotation(String[]values, String defaultValue) {
  AnnotationDescriptor<AllowedValues> descriptor = new AnnotationDescriptor<AllowedValues>( AllowedValues.class );
  descriptor.setValue( "values", values );
  descriptor.setValue( "defaultValue", defaultValue );

  return AnnotationFactory.create( descriptor );
}
```

You would need to depend on Hibernate Validator internal classes, but for testing purposes this should be fine. Of course you could also just create your own proxy framework.

Answer (score 11):

I used the below pattern:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AllowedValuesValidatorTest {

    @Mock
    AllowedValuesValidator allowedValuesValidator;

    @Mock
    ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        doCallRealMethod().when(allowedValuesValidator).initialize(any());
        when(allowedValuesValidator.isValid(any(), any())).thenCallRealMethod();

        AllowedValuesValidatorTestClass testClass = new AllowedValuesValidatorTestClass();

        allowedValuesValidator.initialize(testClass);

    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValidWithValidValues() {
        assertTrue(allowedValuesValidator.isValid("Value", constraintValidatorContext));
    }

    private class AllowedValuesValidatorTestClass implements AllowedValues {

        @Override
        public String message() {
            return "Test Message";
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?>[] groups() {
            return new Class[]{};
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() {
            return new Class[]{};
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
            return AllowedValues.class;
        }

    }

}
```

We can mock the class we are testing. As an annotation is just an interface we can pass in a concrete implementation as the parameter to initialise (which you can make behave any way you need in order to initialise your test correctly). You can then pass in a mock `ConstraintValidatorContext` to your `isValid` method. However, you may need to do some extra work depending on what that method does, if it interacts with the context you may need to do some further mocking.

Comment: If you remove mock from the validator you can also remove `doCallRealMethod()`

Comment: Along with the validator test class, I found you can verify the message provided when providing an invalid value to the validator by creating a test class that implements `ConstraintValidatorContext` rather than using a mock context. In that context implementation, then when `isValid()` is called on the validator, you can save the value coming in to the context's `buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(value)` method to a class var and read that back out to check the resulting message.

Answer (score 5):

Annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NoWhitespacesValidator.class)
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NoWhitespaces {
    String message() default "Not valid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
public class NoWhitespacesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NoWhitespaces, String> {
    @Override public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !value.contains(" ");
    }
}
```

TestCase:

```
class NoWhitespacesTest {

    private NoWhitespacesValidator validator = new NoWhitespacesValidator();

    @Nested
    class NoWhitespaceValidFlow {
        @Test
        void isValid_shouldReturnTrue_whenNoWhitespaces() {
            assertTrue(isValid(""));
            assertTrue(isValid("foo.bar"));
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class NoWhitespacesInvalidFlow {
        @Test
        void isValid_shouldReturnFalse_whenAtLeastOneWhitespace() {
            assertFalse(isValid(" "));
            assertFalse(isValid("foo bar"));
            assertFalse(isValid("  foo"));
            assertFalse(isValid("foo  "));
        }
    }

    private boolean isValid(String value) {
        return validator.isValid(value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder how this can compile since your `isValid()` method requires a ConstraintValidationContext

Answer (score 5):

As @Rammgarot suggest , it works fine but if we change his code , for example the validations rules must be  next : "no white spaces" and must begin with the word "stack" 
NoWhitesSpace.java

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NoWhitespacesValidator.class)
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface NoWhitesSpace {
  
    String value() default "stack"; 
    String message() default "Not valid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

NoWhitespacesValidator.java

```
public class NoWhitespacesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NoWhitesSpace, String> {


   String prefix;

   public void initialize(NoWhitesSpace constraint) {
     prefix =  constraint.value();
   }

   public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

      boolean result = !value.contains(" ") && value.startsWith(prefix);

      return result;

   }
}
```

The test will not pass and the code will generate NullPointerException.

For me, i find the  solution with mock. 
 -> Customer is a simple class entity with fields , setters and getters. 
NoWhitespacesValidatorTest.java

```
class NoWhitespacesValidatorTest {

    private NoWhitesSpace noWhitesSpace = mock(NoWhitesSpace.class);

    private ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext = mock(ConstraintValidatorContext.class);

    @Test
    public void itShouldBeValidWhenItStartsWithPrefixAndWithoutWhiteSpace(){

        when(noWhitesSpace.value()).thenReturn("stack");

        NoWhitespacesValidator noWhitespacesValidator=new NoWhitespacesValidator();
        noWhitespacesValidator.initialize(noWhitesSpace);

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCourseCode("stack");

        boolean result = noWhitespacesValidator.isValid(customer.getCourseCode(),constraintValidatorContext);

        assertTrue(result);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Hardy's answer is pretty good but if you use **hibernate-validator-6.5.1.Final** the constructor that @Hardy's used **AnnotationDescriptor** has another parameter and also it is private. You can check  AnnotationDescriptor constructors  [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/util/annotation/AnnotationDescriptor.html) . So what i did so far, just combine @Rammgarot and @JCollerton answers. Here is the another way to test validator.

```
public class AllowedValuesValidatorTest {

    private AllowedValuesValidator validator;
    String[] allowedValues = {"Y", "N"};
    String defaultValue = "";

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        validator = new AllowedValuesValidator();
        validator.initialize(createAnnotation(allowedValues, defaultValue));
    }

    @Test
    void isValid() {
        // your test here
    }

    private boolean isValid(String value) {
        return validator.isValid(value, null);
    }

    private AllowedValues createAnnotation(String[] allowedValues, String defaultValue) {
        return new AllowedValues() {
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String message() {
                return "Please provide a valid id";
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?>[] groups() {
                return new Class[0];
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() {
                return new Class[0];
            }

            @Override
            public String[] allowedValues() {
                return allowedValues;
            }

             @Override
             public String defaultValue() {
                return defaultValue;
             }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is an old question, but I happened to look for tips to do this same thing (no good ones found). I carved out the following test which feels a proper/decent way to do this.*

I don't see it very handy to mock stuff. Instead the constraints should be testable by using the framework itself.
This is how I managed to make constraint validation to work with a Spring Boot project.

I'm not providing code for the constraint itself (does not differ from examples around), but only a clean way to actually test it.

1. Create a simple service at **src/test**. (Don't create a dummy-service to the  src/main just for testing purposes)

   ```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
    import annotation.NewUserConstraint;
    import entity.UserInfo;

    @Service
    @Validated // Important: The constraint won't work without this
    public class ConstraintTestingService {

        /**
         * The parameter is validated according to constraint rules specified with {@link NewUserConstraint}.
         * @param user The object target for constraint validation.
         * @return <code>True</code> when the validation passes. 
         */
        public boolean testConstraint(@NewUserConstraint UserInfo user) {
            return true;
        }
     }
   ```
2. Create a SpringBoot test.

   ```
    import java.util.Set;
    import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
    import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

    import ConstraintTestingService;
    import entity.UserInfo;

    @SpringBootTest
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    public class ConstraintTest extends Assertions {
    @Autowired
    private ConstraintTestingService constraintTest;

    @Test
    public void testNewUserConstraint() {
        var user = new UserInfo("12345");
        var exception = assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> this.constraintTest.testConstraint(user));
        var violations = exception.getConstraintViolations();
        assertNotNull(violations);
        assertEquals(2, violations.size());
        // Do what rest is needed to check the validation messages from violations
    }
   ```

}